# get index of Select Option from Text value

Tags: javascript, select

I can't recall how to get the index of the option from the text without using a for loop.
Is there an easy way?

Let's say I have a select like this:

```
<select id="prefix-select" name="survey[Prefix]" onchange="changeMade();">
  <option value="0">Mr.</option>
  <option value="1">Mrs.</option>
  <option value="2">Ms.</option>
  <option value="3">Dr.</option>
  <option value="4">Sr.</option>
  <option value="5">Sra.</option>
  <option value="6">Srta.</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to get the index when I have a text of '.Ms'

Comment: Using a library would be easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery way:

```
var str = "Sr.";
index = $("#prefix-select > option:contains("+str+")").index())
```